# Having a bit of trouble tcp connecting in Android Client

Tags: android, authentication, tcp, client

This might be a complex problem with my application but I'll do my best to describe it as accurately as I can.

I am making an Android Client and making use of a couple of helper classes someone else handed to me at work. The helper Android classes are called TcpClient.java and PVDCAndroidClient.java. PVDCAndroidClient.java makes use out of the TcpCLient, using a tcpCLient object to connect via serverIP and port.

Here is PVDCAndroidClient.java:

```
    public class PVDCAndroidClient {

    // constants
    public static final String DEFAULT_LOGIN_URI = "http://me.net:8000/";


    private TcpClient tcpClient = null;
    private UdpClient udpClient = null;
    private boolean connected = false;
    private boolean loggedin = false;
    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    private String loginURI = DEFAULT_LOGIN_URI;
    private int getUserNumber;
    TcpMessageListener listener = null;

    /**
     * Connects to proxy server, blocks until complete or timeout
     * @param serverIP
     * @param port
     */
    public void connect(String serverIP, int port)
    {
        try
          {
            if(serverIP.length() != 0 && port != 0)
            {
              tcpClient = new TcpClient();

              tcpClient.addTcpListener(listener);
              tcpClient.connect(serverIP, port);

            }
          }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Could not connect to server, possbile timeout...", "error");
        }



    }

    ///// Make login function a blocking call

    // Default login, use last location as login location
    public boolean login(String fName, String lName, String password)
    {
        return this.login(fName, lName, password, "last location");
    }

    public boolean login(String fName, String lName, String password, String region)
    {
        return this.login(fName, lName, password, "last location", 128, 128, 20);
    }

    public boolean login(String fName, String lName, String password, String region, int loginX, int loginY, int loginZ)
    {            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
                 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        // Check passed values
            // x, y and z should be between [0, 256]
            // strings should not be null or empty(except lName which can be empty)
        if((loginX >= 0 && loginX <= 256) && (loginY >=0 && loginY <= 256) && (loginZ >= 0 && loginZ <= 256))
        {
            if(fName.length() != 0 && fName != null)
            {


                // Construct packet xml structure

                // Send request and wait until reply or timeout

                // return false if timeout (or throw exception?)
                // if not timeout, read result packet and determine return value

                // getUserNumber = tcpClient.getUserNum();

                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();


                XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

                try {

                    serializer.setOutput(stringWriter);

                    // Indentation is not required, but helps with reading
                    serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

                    // TODO: Remove hardcoding of strings, make either constants or place in strings.xml
                    // TODO: Move the header construction to other method as it is fairly constant other than request num and no need to repeat that much code
                    serializer.startTag("", "pvdc_pkt");

                        serializer.startTag("", "pvdc_header");




                            // TODO: replace this with a string unique to the system
                            serializer.startTag("", "ID");
                                serializer.text("838393djdjdjd");
                            serializer.endTag("", "ID");

                            // TODO: replace this with actual user number from server
                            serializer.startTag("", "user_num");
                                serializer.text("22");//get userNum from above
                            serializer.endTag("", "user_num");

                            // TODO: add a request number counter to increment this on each request
                            serializer.startTag("", "request_num");
                                serializer.text("1");
                            serializer.endTag("", "request_num");

                            serializer.startTag("", "DateTime");
                                serializer.text(sdf.toString()); //utc time variable.
                            serializer.endTag("", "DateTime");

                        serializer.endTag("", "pvdc_header");

                        serializer.startTag("", "pvdc_content");
                            serializer.attribute("", "type", "requestlogin");

                            serializer.startTag("", "name");
                                serializer.attribute("", "fname", fName);
                                serializer.attribute("", "lname", lName);
                            serializer.endTag("", "name");

                            serializer.startTag("", "password");
                                serializer.text(password);
                            serializer.endTag("", "password");

                            serializer.startTag("", "server");
                                serializer.text(this.loginURI);
                            serializer.endTag("", "server");

                            serializer.startTag("", "location");
                                serializer.attribute("", "region", region);
                                serializer.text(loginX + ";" + loginY +";" + loginZ);
                            serializer.endTag("", "location");

                        serializer.endTag("", "pvdc_content");

                    serializer.endTag("", "pvdc_pkt");

                    // Finish writing
                    serializer.endDocument();
                    // write xml data out
                    serializer.flush();

                    // 
                    sendLogin(stringWriter);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception", "error occurred while creating xml file");
                    return false;
                }
                // Print out xml for debugging
                Log.d("PVDCAndroidClient Login", stringWriter.toString().trim());

            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Error in name checking", "fName either blank or null");
            }

         }
        else
        {
            Log.d("login coordinates X,Y, or Z not between 0-256", "Coordinates Error");
        }

        return true;
       }


    // moveString should contain the properly formatted movement command(s)[see above move request description]
    public void sendLogin(StringWriter stringWriter)
    {
        tcpClient.sendMessage(stringWriter.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the actual TcpClient.java:

```
    public class TcpClient {

    public interface TcpMessageListener{

        public void onMessage(TcpClient client, String message);
    }

    private Socket socket = null;
    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private BufferedReader in = null;
    private Thread listenThread = null;
    private boolean listening = false;
    private int userNum = -1;
    private List<TcpMessageListener> listeners = new ArrayList<TcpMessageListener>();


    public int getUserNum()
    {
        return this.userNum;
    }

    public TcpClient() {

    }

    public void addTcpListener(TcpMessageListener listener)
    {
        synchronized(this.listeners)
        {
            this.listeners.add(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeTcpListener(TcpMessageListener listener)
    {
        synchronized(this.listeners)
        {
            this.listeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    public boolean connect(String serverIpOrHost, int port) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverIpOrHost, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                public void run() {
                    int charsRead = 0;
                    char[] buff = new char[4096];
                    while(listening && charsRead >= 0)
                    {
                        try {
                            charsRead = in.read(buff);
                            if(charsRead > 0)
                            {
                                Log.d("TCPClient",new String(buff).trim());
                                String input = new String(buff).trim();
                                synchronized(listeners)
                                {
                                    for(TcpMessageListener l : listeners){
                                        l.onMessage(TcpClient.this, input);
                                    }
                                }

                                if (input.toLowerCase().contains("<user_num>")){
                                    int index = input.toLowerCase().indexOf("<user_num>");
                                    index += "<user_num>".length();
                                    int index2 = input.toLowerCase().indexOf("</user_num>");
                                    userNum = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(index,  index2));

                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("TCPClient", "IOException while reading input stream");
                            listening = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

            this.listening = true;
            this.listenThread.setDaemon(true);
            this.listenThread.start();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host");
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection");
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage().toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        if(out != null)
        {
            out.println(msg);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            if(out != null){
                out.close();
                out = null;
            }
            if(in != null){
                in.close();
                in = null;
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
                socket = null;
            }
            if(this.listenThread != null){
                this.listening = false;
                this.listenThread.interrupt();
            }
            this.userNum = -1;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("I/O error in closing connection.");
        }
    }
}
```

LASTLY, here is what I have been coding today and cannot seem to get this to work. I don't get any blatant exceptions, just a warning on Logcat, that says, "Couldn't get I/O for the connection".

```
    public class AndroidClientCompnt extends Activity {

    private TcpClient myTcpClient = null;
    private UdpClient udpClient;
    private static final String IP_ADDRESS_SHARED_PREFS = "ipAddressPref";
    private static final String PORT_SHARED_PREFS = "portNumberPref";
    private String encryptPassLoginActivity;
    private String getIpAddressSharedPrefs;
    private String getPassword, getName, getRegionSelect, getGridSelect;
    private String fName, lName;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private boolean resultCheck = false;
    private int portNum;
    PVDCAndroidClient client;
    private String name;
    private CharSequence[] getView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // getting object's properties from LoginActivity class.

        getName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        getPassword = intent.getStringExtra("password");
        getRegionSelect = intent.getStringExtra("regionSelect");
        getGridSelect = intent.getStringExtra("gridSelect");

        Log.d("VARIABLES", "getName = " + getName + "getPassword" + getPassword
                + "getRegionSelect = " + getRegionSelect + ".");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        client = new PVDCAndroidClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Take care of getting user's login information:

        // grid selected as well? sometime?

        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        getIpAddressSharedPrefs = settings.getString(IP_ADDRESS_SHARED_PREFS,
                "");
        portNum = Integer.parseInt(settings.getString(PORT_SHARED_PREFS, ""));
        Log.d("SHARED" + getIpAddressSharedPrefs + "port " + portNum, "");

        if (getIpAddressSharedPrefs.length() != 0 && portNum != 0) {

            try {
                // first connect attempt.

                client.connect(getIpAddressSharedPrefs, portNum);
                resultCheck = client.isConnected();

                // here is where I want to call Async to do login
                // or do whatever else.

                UploadTask task = new UploadTask();
                task.execute();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Ip preference and port blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        finish();
    }

    private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... names) {

            // encrypting user's password with Md5Hash class.
            try {
                encryptPassLoginActivity = MdHashing
                        .MD5(getPassword.toString());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (resultCheck == true) {

                String[] firstAndLast;

                String spcDelmt = " ";

                firstAndLast = name.toString().split(spcDelmt);

                fName = firstAndLast[0];
                lName = firstAndLast[1];

                // set up the tcp client to sent the information to the
                // server.
                client.login(fName, lName, encryptPassLoginActivity,
                        getRegionSelect, 128, 128, 20);

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            Intent goToInWorld = new Intent(
                    AndroidClientCompnt.this.getApplicationContext(),
                    PocketVDCActivity.class);
            startActivity(goToInWorld);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

}
```

I know this is a super long post and I am asking a lot but if anyone could take a look at this I would very much appreciate it. I've been at this all day, trying to make use of these helper classes I got and can't get it to work. It also doesn't help that I'm not too experienced in this client/server stuff. Any nudges in the right direction or an accepted solution would REALLY mean something to me.

Thank you kindly,

Have a good evening.

Comment: one thing is you might need certain permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Yes, I did. I definitely wouldn't want to make anyone upset. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure you have the following permission in your Android-Manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET/>
```

w/o this you definitely won't be making any tcp/ip connections.

2) You will want to run the code in debug mode, and place breakpoints where the connection information
   is set and also what results are at several points.  In other words you need to dig deeper.

If you are somewhat new to coding there is no better investment of time than in running the debugger and stepping line by line through the code.  Code only comes to life inside a debugger, where you can see the values of variables and results.  So set several breakpoints, step through and you will see more.  It is more difficult to debug where there are threads however.

Comment: Actually I have recently ran the debugger and stepped into when the connection is formed. I found out a couple of things: 1. I don't think my parse of fName and lName is even happening or client.login for that matter all because resultCheck == false because there was no connection. 2. The listener appears to have a value of false under the category of "listening." I will add the permission to my manifest and see what happens.

Comment: So, I added it to my manifest and debugged again and this time A LOT of different stuff happened, in a good way. The listening that was false went to true and a new TCP client connection showed up on my UNIX terminal!!! This is so exciting it's actually doing something now. I will continue to tweak it, but at least the server is actually acknowledging that I'm trying to do something. THANK YOU. I've asked others and no one ever said anything about the permission in the manifest. I guess I will know to suggest it to others in the future as well.

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  Keep posting.  Stackoverflow is a happening place.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your manifest?

You may need to add the following :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Additionally - I assume you see nothing ever happen on the server side of this connection?

Comment: Thank you as well. Stack Overflow is one of the most wonderful things I've come across in awhile and it can really help out people in a pinch.